# Open AutoCompleteBox in WPF on control focus

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete

I'm trying to open `System.Windows.Controls.AutoCompleteBox` on control focus. The event triggers but nothing happens:/ When I start entering some text, the autocomplete box works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
AutoCompleteBox box = new AutoCompleteBox();
box.Text = textField.Value ?? "";
box.ItemsSource = textField.Proposals;
box.FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains;
box.GotFocus += (sender, args) =>
    {
        box.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    };
```

Comment: Not much experience with Silverlight here, but perhaps it is worth trying to do `box.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() = > { box.IsDropDownOpen = true; }))`. My suspicion is that the handling of the Focus event internally by the control gets in the way of you opening the dropdown. Using the Dispatcher queue, you could let the dropdown open *after* the Focus event has been processed completely.

Comment: Another reason might be, that the *AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains* doesn't allow the dropdown to open, if no items match. Try with *AutoCompleteFilterMode.None* and see what happens...

Comment: Both proposals helped, but there is one more problem. Everything works when there is something written in the box - when nothing, dropdown doesn't appear at all:(

Comment: Do you mean, the dropdown doesn't appear even if AutoCompleteFilterMode.None is used and the *ItemsSource* of AutoCompleteBox contains at least one element (a-ka non-empty)?

Comment: Yes, exactly as u described that:/

Comment: After setting the ItemsSource, the *AutoCompleteBox.PopulateComplete* should perhaps be invoked as well (according to its documentation, but might only be required if you handle the population event).

Comment: By the way, if you want to discuss some more, how about going into chat?

Comment: I did a workaround dealing with `AutoCompleteFilterMode` :) Thanks for help

Comment: Would you mind to post the working code snippet as answer (even if you are answering your own question)? It might be helpful to know for others who are stuck in a similar problem...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did a quick workaround as if this solution is satisfying for me in my program.

```
AutoCompleteBox box = new AutoCompleteBox();
box.Text = textField.Value ?? "";
if (textField.Proposals != null)
{
    box.ItemsSource = textField.Proposals;
    box.FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.None;
    box.GotFocus += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text))
            {
                box.Text = " "; // when empty, we put a space in the box to make the dropdown appear
            }
            box.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => box.IsDropDownOpen = true);
        };
    box.LostFocus += (sender, args) =>
        {
            box.Text = box.Text.Trim();
        };
    box.TextChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(box.Text) &&
                box.FilterMode != AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains)
            {
                box.FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.Contains;
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(box.Text) &&
                box.FilterMode != AutoCompleteFilterMode.None)
            {
                box.FilterMode = AutoCompleteFilterMode.None;
            }
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution from @elgonzo worked perfectly for me.

XAML:

```
<wpftk:AutoCompleteBox FilterMode="Contains"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding List}"
                       MinimumPrefixLength="0"
                       Text="{Binding Text}"
                       GotFocus="AutoCompleteBox_GotFocus"/>
```

with namespace

```
xmlns:wpftk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
```

and Code-Behind:

```
private void AutoCompleteBox_GotFocus(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var _acb = sender as AutoCompleteBox;
    if(_acb != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(_acb.Text))
    {
        _acb.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { _acb.IsDropDownOpen = true; }));
    }
}
```

The dropdown appears when there is no text entered yet and the AutoCompleteBox got focus.